# Word Document Multiple Backgrounds

Tags: c#, ms-word, watermark

I have a file "test.docx" with 3 page sections, and each section is unlinked from the previous page. Now I want to be able to set a different background/watermark for each section. I just don't know how to select the other 2 sections (or.. not the first one).

I tried it like this:

```
Application nWord = new Application();
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object fileName = @"E:\test.docx";
Document nDoc = nWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref
oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref
oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref
oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
Shape nShape = null;

for (int i = 0; i < nDoc.Sections.Count; i++)
{
    nShape =
    nDoc.Sections[i].Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1,
    "TEXT" + i.ToString(), "Arial", (float)36, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, ref oMissing);

    nShape.Fill.Visible =
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    nShape.Line.Visible =
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
    nShape.Fill.Solid();
    nShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)WdColor.wdColorGray20;
    nShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition =
    WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
    nShape.RelativeVerticalPosition =
    WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
    nShape.Left = (float)WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
    nShape.Top = (float)WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
}
nWord.Visible = true;
```

but it just drops all 3 watermarks on the first section.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a work around, after 3 days of searching and discussing. Here's my solution:

```
//initialize
Application WordApp = new Application();
Document adoc = WordApp.Documents.Add();
Selection selection = adoc.ActiveWindow.Selection;
Shape wmShape;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object linktofile = false;
object savewithdocument = true;
object CurrentPage = WdFieldType.wdFieldPage;
object TotalPages = WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages;

//load background images
List<string> images = new List<string>();
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg");
images.Add(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg");

//create all sections
object breaktype = WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
for (int i = 0; i < images.Count - 1; i++)
{
    adoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument;
    selection.InsertBreak(ref breaktype);
    adoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
    selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = false;
}

//set background images
for (int i = 0; i < adoc.Sections.Count; i++)
{
    //select section header
    adoc.Sections[i+1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Select();

    //insert pagenumbers
    adoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
    selection.TypeText("Pagina ");
    selection.Fields.Add(selection.Range, ref CurrentPage, ref missing, ref missing);
    selection.TypeText(" van ");
    selection.Fields.Add(selection.Range, ref TotalPages, ref missing, ref missing);

    //insert shape
    wmShape = selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(images[i], ref linktofile, ref savewithdocument).ConvertToShape();

    //modify shape properties
    wmShape.Select(ref missing);
    wmShape.Name = "WordPictureWatermark862903805";
    wmShape.PictureFormat.Brightness = (float)0.5;
    wmShape.PictureFormat.Contrast = (float)0.5;
    wmShape.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
    wmShape.Height = WordApp.InchesToPoints((float)11.7);
    wmShape.Width = WordApp.InchesToPoints((float)8.3);
    wmShape.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = -1;
    wmShape.WrapFormat.Side = WdWrapSideType.wdWrapBoth;
    wmShape.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
    wmShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
    wmShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
    wmShape.Left = (float)WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
    wmShape.Top = (float)WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;

}

WordApp.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

WtFudgE

If it is dropping all water marks in same place then there could be a possibility that the sections are linked. One way to check would be to open the Word document and do the following

Open the Headers and Footers Tabs and in the Options, go to the Headers and Layouts and select "Different First Page"

Once you have done that now test your code. :)

What MS Word Version are you using? Maybe, I can post a relevant snapshot?

Comment: Also please confirm the VS version so that I can test the code before pasting.

Comment: No they are not linked :) I already said all pages are unlinked from the previous page.

I'm using word 2007 and visual studio 2010

Comment: @WtFudgE: Great. One last request. Can you upload the document on wikisend.com and paste the link here so that I can test my code with it?